# How to clear select element

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've got a design where I'm adding a chip to my page by selecting an item from a dropdown.  And I can remove a chip by clicking on it.  However, I can't seem to clear the select element's value. I've tried several things, but none of them work.

Using Angular Material select element: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/KU1CxBqLwG5XtbvyEjJj?p=preview

Using Angular select element:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ewSlIRDHii3PnXRtnKgw?p=preview

html:

```
<div class="chips-overview-example">
  <md-card>
    <md-toolbar color="primary">Dynamic Chips</md-toolbar>
    <md-card-content>
      <md-chip-list>
        <md-chip *ngFor="let person of people" (click)="remove($event)">
          {{person.name}}
        </md-chip>

        <md-select id="names" 
                   placeholder="Names" 
                   [ngModel]="name"
                   (ngModelChange)="add($event)">
          <md-option *ngFor="let name of names" 
                     value="{{name.code}}">
            {{name.name}}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-chip-list>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Output} from '@angular/core';

export interface Person {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'chips-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['chips-overview-example.css']
})
export class ChipsOverviewExample {
  visible: boolean = true;
  @Output() nameForm;

  names = [
    {code: "F",name: "Frank",description: ""},
    {code: "G",name: "George",description: ""},
    {code: "H",name: "Henry",description: ""},
    {code: "I",name: "Inigo",description: ""},
    {code: "J",name: "Jose",description: ""},
    {code: "K",name: "Kevin",description: ""}
  ];

  removedNames = [];

  people: Person[] = [];

  add(selection): void {
    let selected = this.names.find(el => el.code === selection);
    console.log("adding: ", selected, " to ", JSON.stringify(this.people));

    this.people.push({name: selected.name});

    this.removedNames.push(selected);
    this.names.splice(this.names.findIndex(el => el === selected), 1);
  }

  remove(chip) {
    let name = chip.target.innerText;
    let index = this.people.findIndex(el => el.name === name);
    this.people.splice(index, 1);
    this.names.push(this.removedNames.find(el => el.name === name));
    this.removedNames.splice(this.removedNames.findIndex(el => el.name === name), 1);
    this.names.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
  }



  toggleVisible(): void {
    this.visible = false;
  }
}
```

main.ts (module)

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
import {ChipsOverviewExample} from './chips-overview-example';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],

  declarations: [ChipsOverviewExample],
  bootstrap: [ChipsOverviewExample],
  providers: []
})
export class PlunkerAppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(PlunkerAppModule);
```

Comment: Cleaning the ngModel: `this.name = ''`?

Comment: That works once, but the second time it fails.  Also, I've just noticed that it is adding the chip despite the if conditional in my add() method.

Comment: what if you just add an option with an empty value? `<md-option  value=""></md-option>` before other options? And of course later on `this.name = ''`

Comment: It's really strange. I tried something here and it's not clearing after the *second* time. But for sure, you have to set an *empty* `option` like @smnbbrv mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this by adding a feature.  During the process of adding a chip, I also remove the value from the dropdown list. The user can no longer select it, and neither can the system.

Unfortunately, when I delete the chip, I add that option back to the dropdown list. If that option was the last one selected, it appears on the input box.

Not full (fool) proof.

Anyway, here is the update add() and remove() methods.

```
  removedNames = [];

  add(selection): void {
    console.log("nameForm", this.nameForm);

    let selectedName = this.names.find(el => el.code === selection).name;
    console.log("adding: ", selectedName, " to ", this.people)

    if (this.people.findIndex(person => person.name === selectedName) < 0) {
      this.people.push({name: selectedName});
    }
    this.nameForm = '';
    this.removedNames.push(this.names.find(el => el.code === selection));
    this.names.splice(this.names.findIndex(el => el.code === selection), 1);
  }

  remove(chip) {
    let name = chip.target.innerText;
    let index = this.people.findIndex(el => el.name === name);
    this.people.splice(index, 1);
    this.names.push(this.removedNames.find(el => el.name === name));
    this.removedNames.splice(this.removedNames.findIndex(el => el.name === name), 1);
  }
```

The final answer is to modify the value directly using the patchValue method on the formGroup. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#set-data